# Grammar justification for 「〜わりに（は）」

Tags: etymology, definitions

I recently came across this expression「〜わりに（は）」 An example:

> りんごは、安い**わりには**美味しい。([source](http://www.imabi.net/considering.htm))
> Apples are delicious, **considering how** cheap they are.

What I don't understand is **why**?

The dictionary entry for わり brings up the following definitions (thanks jisho.org):

> 1. rate; ratio; proportion; percentage​
> 2. profit​
> 3. assignment​
> 4. 10%; unit of ten percent​
> 5. match; schedule of matches​
> 6. diluted with (of drinks); mixed with
> 7. Wari (place)

In the example above, わり modifies 安い, and I just can't understand how to translate it literally?

One interesting thing is that I found this definition in a J-J dictionary:

> ５ （「…わりに」の形で）ある事から予想・推測される程度。…に応じた程度よりは。「値段の割りに品物がよい」「若い割りには礼儀正しい」

Which loosely translates to:

> (In the form of わりに): More than expected/guessed.

So I'm wondering whether this is just an additional definition to わり (like an exception the applies in this specific form), or there is some historical reason, or perhaps a literal translation that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the わり means the #**1: rate, proportion**. In my opinion, "**rather**" can work as well.

> リンゴは安い割りには、美味しい：

*Apples are delicious, considering that it **is rated as** "inexpensive" of the three categories: "inexpensive," "reasonable," and "expensive."*

*Apples are delicious, considering that they are **rather** cheap.*

Answer (score 0):

ご質問に付されている原文中の「わりには」の意味に対して、質問者様が提示されているものの中でマッチするのはJ-J dictionaryの５の意味です。

> ５ （「…わりに」の形で）ある事から予想・推測される程度。…に応じた程度よりは。「値段の割りに品物がよい」「若い割りには礼儀正しい」

最近スーパーでフルーツの値段を見ていないので大雑把に記載しますが、国産リンゴ１個は１００円前後で売られているとしたら、輸入マンゴー１個は３５０円、国産マンゴー１個はなんと２０００円ぐらいかと。（日本の国産マンゴー生産量は少ない。）ここで例として、仮に、マンゴーがかなり美味しいと思っているとしたときに、さらにマンゴーとリンゴの美味しさが似たようなものだと思うのならば、１００円ぐらいで手に入るその他のフルーツに一般的に期待される味よりおいしいものが買えるというわけです。（何もフルーツ同士で比較する必要はないですが、例としてフルーツ同士でここでは比較しました。）原文は、価格を基準にしてその他のものと比べた結果、（原文の話者は）リンゴは（相対的に）美味しいと伝えていると考えます。