# The vocabulary behind フリの割にボケが面白くない

Tags: grammar, words

I can't find a concrete definition for the vocabulary in this sentence. "フリの割にボケが面白くない" **フリ** seems to have four different meanings in every japanese dictionary I can find, **割** and **割に** seem to have different definitions that I can't wrap my head around the logic of, and **ボケ** is just a complete mystery to me. The context of this sentence is that someone attempted to make a joke, and the speaker is annoyed at it. I think it translates into something like "*for a joke setup, Bokes aren't interesting*". But I'm not sure and would like a bit of an explanation/clarification to the definition of these words please. And maybe also an explanation as to what the の and に particles are conveying in these instances.

EDIT: Here's the image for extra context:

[image]

Comment: フリ is definitely lead in (into joke) and ボケ should be funny man of a comedy duo

Comment: Judging from the image, looks like フリ and ボケ were said by the same person. So "Your punchline isn't funny for such a (long?) lead-up".

Answer (score 4):

First, basically ボケ is a joke (itself) or a person who tells jokes (or plays the role of telling jokes). I kinda feel *gag* may be better, but may be off. It is mostly about understanding a comedy format in Japanese language.

- [突っ込む所 - is this what it means?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17870/45489)

Next, わりに implies a sort of disproportionality. It can be negative or positive. (cf. [わりに - #2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%89%B2%E3%81%AB/#je-82020))

- [Grammar justification for 「〜わりに（は）」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52492/45489)

E.g.

- このレストランは高いわりにおいしくない - expensiveness and quality of food are disproportional (negative example)
- この本は短いわりに中身が濃い - the book is short but rich in contents (positive)

Lastly, the most relevant sense of [ふり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8A/#jn-195469) is:

> ８ 本題に入るためのきっかけ。前置きとしてする話。「前—」

So understanding it as *setup* is fine. As per the definition, it is a part of the joke that precedes the punchline. Also, it can be used as a signal or cue for  doing something (including telling a joke).

Understanding the sentence requires more context, but one possibility is that the preceding part is lengthy and the final joke is not proportionally funny.